# Installing Silverlight on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, silverlight

How to install Silverlight on Linux?

Is there a package for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight for Linux is made with the [Moonlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_(runtime)) project. You can find more information on their page: http://mono-project.com/Moonlight.

To download for Ubuntu (and Firefox), follow the instructions given [here](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/).

Comment: +1 I suppose Moonlight supports Silverlight 2. support for Silverlight 3 is in progress.